# What is the extended version of the "sl" command?

Tags: shell, command

Recently I've been discussing Unix humor with a friend and we got to the topic of the `sl` command. I got the sources, compiled, installed on our development machine, and... got rather disappointed. The "[official version](https://github.com/mtoyoda/sl)" shows just the engine, with option to expand it to two cars.

I remember a version from a machine I had a couple years ago, that had a road crossing with barriers, a very long train, and dozens of options.

Where can I find that extended version?

Comment: what does `sl` do?

Comment: @chovy The full version displays an animated ascii-art of a railroad crossing, with a lengthy train passing through, The operation of the command can't be interrupted with ctrl-c, so if you mistyped 'ls' in a hurry, you're stuck for a good minute or so watching the train pass by and waiting for the animation to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I installed sl in my ubuntu box (apt-get install sl) I got the binary /usr/games/sl-h too. This is the version you are looking for. You can probably get the sources from the ubuntu packages pages (take a look here: http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/sl/ ).

Comment: In the ubuntu packages page, there are two major version of sl now, one is 3.03 and another is 5.02. according to this man-page, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man6/sl-h.6.html, and my discovery, I found only 3.03 version has command `sl-h`, 5.02 version doesn't.